# CSS not matching to HTML when using Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am trying to create a web app using flask. My style.css file is working correctly some of the time so I know that they are linking correctly but certain parts seem to not be finding the appropriate classes in my HTML templates.

specifically :

```
.error {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
}
```

should match with

```
<div class = "error">
   {{error}}
</div>
```

when I display the HTML in a browser this works correctly, but when I run my flask application the styling is not applied.

what am I missing?

Comment: Please show the part of the template that references your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely not importing the css file correctly.
Let's suppose that your project is structured as follows:

```
├── project/
│   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── main.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── base.html
│   └── static/
│       └── style.css
```

In order to correctly import the css file with flask, you need to do (base.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Error page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="error">
         {{error}}
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In your main app, you also need to correctly render the template (main.py):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/error/<error>')
def error(error):
    return render_template('base.html', error=error)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Moved my css file up from /static/styles to /static and that fixed my issue